# MSS, Python: Maximum number of clients reachedSegmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-mss

I use MSS for Python for capturing screenshots rapidly on my computer, but when putting the image capturing inside a while loop:

```
import mss
while True:
    sct = mss.mss()
```

I get an error message `Maximum number of clients reachedSegmentation fault (core dumped)`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the context manager:

```py
import mss

with mss.mss() as sct:
    while True:
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, and I think it has to do with not closing the mss feed properly. Simply add an `sct.close()` at the end of each iteration:

```
import mss
while True:
    sct = mss.mss()
    sct.close()
```